# how to show that the groups are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

$Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3$ , $Z_4 \times Z_3$ , $D_{12}$, $A_4$

Show that no 2 groups are isomorphic to each other?

$Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_3$ and $Z_4 \times Z_3$): For $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_3$ and $Z_4 \times Z_3$ I said that they are not isomorphic because  $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_3$ has an LCM of 6 vs. 12 so they aren't isomorphic. Am I right?

$Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_3$ and $D_{12}$: I am not sure, but I think because the order of $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_3$ is 6 and $D_{12}$ is 12, they are not isomorphic?

$Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_3$ and $A_4$: ? Not sure?

$Z_4 \times Z_3$ and $D_{12}$: ?

$Z_4 \times Z_3$ and $A_4$: ?

$D_{12}$ and $A_4$: I said they aren't isomorphic because $D_{12}$ has a rotation of order 12 and $A_4$ has order 1, 2 or 3 so they are not. ( Is this correct?)

I'd appreciate if you can tell me if I am right / wrong for the ones I solved and help me solve the remaining ones. Thanks!

Comment: The order of $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/3$ is $2\cdot 2\cdot 3=12$, not $6$.

Comment: For your LCM argument, why does the LCM matter?  $D_{12}$ does not have an element of order $12$, I think (from context) that it has an element of order $6$, i.e., the dihedral group of order $12$.

Comment: Why does it make sense to compare the lcm of $\{2,2,3\}$ with $12$ for $D_{12}$.  The LCM is the maximum order of an element in a product of cyclic groups while the $D_{12}$ refers to the order of the group.

Comment: DO NOT VANDALIZE your own post, miller21!

Answer (score 5):

The first two groups are abelian but are not isomorphic because they have different exponents. Actually, the second group is cyclic but the first one is not.

The last two groups not abelian and so cannot be isomorphic to the any of the first two groups.

$D_{12}$ has an element of order $6$ but $A_4$ doesn't and so they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of order 2 or something like that. If they are isomorphic then the numbers would be the same